# Initializing nested anonymous struct

Tags: go, struct

I want to handle struct inside struct with func :
my code :

```
package models

type CalendarPushNotification struct {
    Id                  string      `db:"id"`
    UserId              string      `db:"user_id"`
    EventId             string      `db:"event_id"`
    Title               string      `db:"title"`
    StartDate           string      `db:"start_date"`
    PushDate            string      `db:"push_date"`
    PushDeliveryLineId  string      `db:"push_delivery_line_id"`
    IsPushDelivered     string      `db:"is_push_delivered"`
}
type ResponseGetCalendar    struct {
    View struct {
        EventId            string `db:"event_id"`
        Title              string `db:"title"`
        StartDate          string `db:"start_date"`
        PushDate           string `db:"push_date"`
        PushDeliveryLineId string `db:"push_delivery_line_id"`
        IsPushDelivered    string `db:"is_push_delivered"`
    }`json:"schedules"`
}
var CalendarUtils = CalendarPushNotification{}

func (CalendarPushNotification) GetResponseGetCalendar(model *CalendarPushNotification) * ResponseGetCalendar {
    return &ResponseGetCalendar{
            EventId:            model.EventId,
            Title:              model.Title,
            StartDate:          model.StartDate,
            PushDate:           model.PushDate,
            PushDeliveryLineId: model.PushDeliveryLineId,
            IsPushDelivered:    model.IsPushDelivered,
    }
}
```

my func `GetResponseGetCalendar` cannot see the members inside the `ResponseGetCalendar struct` when returning the struct .

[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: You are missing the View member

Comment: View.EventID , i tried but not ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make View a non anonymous struct, you can do something like this:

```
type View struct {
    EventId            string `db:"event_id"`
    Title              string `db:"title"`
    StartDate          string `db:"start_date"`
    PushDate           string `db:"push_date"`
    PushDeliveryLineId string `db:"push_delivery_line_id"`
    IsPushDelivered    string `db:"is_push_delivered"`
}
type ResponseGetCalendar struct {
    Schedules View `json:"schedules"`
}

var CalendarUtils = CalendarPushNotification{}

func (CalendarPushNotification) GetResponseGetCalendar(model *CalendarPushNotification) *ResponseGetCalendar {
    return &ResponseGetCalendar{
        Schedules: View{
            EventId:            model.EventId,
            Title:              model.Title,
            StartDate:          model.StartDate,
            PushDate:           model.PushDate,
            PushDeliveryLineId: model.PushDeliveryLineId,
            IsPushDelivered:    model.IsPushDelivered,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`View` is an anonymous struct. Initializing anonymous structs can be tedious. You have to do:

```
&ResponseGetCalendar{
   View: struct { // List all elements of View here}
            { // List them again and initialize them here}
}
```

Instead, you can do:

```
 ret:= &ResponseGetCalendar{}
 ret.View.EventId=model.EventId
 ...
 return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is because of the missing struct View inside the ResponseGetCalendar struct. Replace your `GetResponseGetCalendar func` with the following one:

```
func (CalendarPushNotification) GetResponseGetCalendar(model *CalendarPushNotification) *ResponseGetCalendar {
    ret := &ResponseGetCalendar{}
    ret.View.EventId = model.EventId
    ret.View.Title = model.Title
    ret.View.StartDate = model.StartDate
    ret.View.PushDate = model.PushDate
    ret.View.PushDeliveryLineId = model.PushDeliveryLineId
    ret.View.IsPushDelivered = model.IsPushDelivered
    return ret
}
```